# \maketitle not printing twice

Tags: titles

I am trying to `\maketitle` on the my title page and then also on the first page of the body of the paper.

Here is what I have:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}

\title{#}
\author{#}
\date{#}

\begin{document}

    \begin{titlepage}
        \maketitle
        \thispagestyle{empty}  % no page #
    \end{titlepage}

    % Start paper
    \maketitle

    % 1.5 spacing
    \onehalfspacing

    % start the paper

\end{document}
```

For some reason the title is only printing out on the title page. Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Typically, when setting the title via `\maketitle`, the entire titling-structure is cleared after its used.

We can avoid this clearing by setting the title using an internal macro `\@maketitle`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\settitle}{\@maketitle}
\makeatother

\title{A title}
\author{An author}
\date{A date}

\begin{document}

\settitle
\thispagestyle{empty}
\addtocounter{page}{-1}

\clearpage

% Start paper
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Some page correction is needed, if you want the first page of your article to start with page 1.

Alternatively, using the [`titling` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/titling) directly avoids this removal, allowing you to use `\maketitle` multiple times within your document. Just add

```
\usepackage{titling}
```

to your preamble.

Comment: Beautiful. The titling package worked perfect. Thanks @Werner.

Answer (score 3):

`\maketitle` clears everything related to the title, for memory preservation.

You can define a `\maketitlepage` command that also avoids printing the contents of `\thanks` in the title page.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\maketitlepage}{%
  \begin{titlepage}
    \let\thanks\@gobble
    \let\footnote\@gobble
    \if@twocolumn
      \ifnum \col@number=\@ne
        \@maketitle
      \else
        \twocolumn[\@maketitle]%
      \fi
    \else
      \@maketitle
    \fi
    \thispagestyle{empty}
  \end{titlepage}%
}
\makeatother


\title{Title}
\author{Author\thanks{The author was financially supported by TeX.Stackexchange}}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitlepage

% Start paper
\maketitle

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]