# How to make two title pages like in scientific magazines?

Tags: titles, article, page

I have been trying to create a TeX file with two different title pages but really similar to eachother *(like when you have a scientific magazine)*.

My problem is that the first page is exactly like i wanted *(it has the page header with an image and the footer with the name of the Magazine, DOI, etc.)* but the second one doesn't have the style i want *(only has the title of the article and the name of the autor and it's not with the indentation i wanted)*.

This is what i have:

```
\documentclass[twoside,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amsfonts, latexsym, amssymb, amstext}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\pagestyle{fancyplain}

\lhead[\fancyplain{}{\thepage}]{} \rhead[ \
]{\fancyplain{}{\thepage}}

\chead[{\fancyplain{}{\sc Something Important}}]{\fancyplain{}{\sc
Someone important}}

\cfoot{\tiny Magazine, pp.\ 1--7 \\ DOI blah}

\setcounter{page}{1}

\title{\sc Something Important}
\author{{\it Someone important} \\ \small{Somewhere in the world}}
\date{}

\maketitle

\vspace{-7cm}

\begin{center} 
\noindent\hspace{-.38cm} \includegraphics[scale=.48]{image}
\noindent\rule{12.7cm}{0.4pt}
\end{center}


\newpage



\chead[{\fancyplain{}{\sc Something}}]{\fancyplain{}{\sc
Someone}}

\cfoot{\tiny Magazine, pp.\ 9--13 \\ DOI blah}


\title{\sc Something}
\author{{\it Someone} \\ \small{Somewhere}}
\date{}


\maketitle

\vspace{-7cm}

\begin{center} 
\noindent\hspace{-.38cm} \includegraphics[scale=.48]{image}
\noindent\rule{12.7cm}{0.4pt}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

I would really appreciate if someone could give me a clue about how to make the second title page be similar to the first one. Thanks!

Comment: Since you use `\maketitle` twicce in your document, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/330358/134144 could be interesting

Comment: you forgot to provide the `\usepackage{fancyhdr}` command in your MWE. it won't compile without it

Answer (score 1):

> Since you use `\maketitle` twicce in your document, [tex.stackexchange.com/q/330358/134144](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/330358/134144) could be interesting – leandriis

Using `\maketitle` resets some stuff. Have a look there for the explanation

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!